# Multi-task learning network structure design

Tags: deep-learning, mxnet

I'm trying to do text classification using CNN. Here's some of my label: `dog`, `cat`, `bird`, `football`, `basketball`... As these classes are somehow too fine-grained to have good precision, plus the relatively small amount of training data, I group them into `animal`, `sports`.

Then I design a simple multi-task learning structure as below **but it doesn't improve final performance** on my fine-grained label.

```
 18     data = mx.symbol.Variable('data')
 19     softmax_label = mx.symbol.Variable('softmax_label')
 20     softmax_label_finegrained = mx.symbol.Variable('softmax_label_finegrained')
 21
 22     # embedding layer
 23     if not with_embedding:
 24         word_embed = mx.symbol.Embedding(data=data, input_dim=vocab_size,
 25                                       output_dim=embedding_size, name='word_embedding')
 26         conv_input = mx.symbol.Reshape(data=word_embed, target_shape=(batch_size, 1, sentence_size, embedding_size))  # convolution layer needs 4D input.
 27     else:
 28         logging.info('with pretrained embedding.')
 29         conv_input = data
 30
 31     # convolution and pooling layer
 32     pooled_outputs = []
 33     for i, filter_size in enumerate(filter_list):
 34         convi = mx.symbol.Convolution(data=conv_input, kernel=(filter_size, embedding_size), num_filter=num_filter)
 35         acti  = mx.symbol.Activation(data=convi, act_type='relu')
 36         pooli = mx.symbol.Pooling(data=acti, pool_type='max', kernel=(sentence_size - filter_size + 1, 1), stride=(1,1))  # max pooling on entire sentence feature ma    p.
 37         pooled_outputs.append(pooli)
 38
 39     # combine all pooled outputs
 40     num_feature_maps = num_filter * len(filter_list)
 41     concat = mx.symbol.Concat(*pooled_outputs, dim=1)  # max-overtime pooling. concat all feature maps into a long feature before feeding into final dropout and full    y connected layer.
 42     h_pool = mx.symbol.Reshape(data=concat, shape=(batch_size, num_feature_maps))  # make it flat/horizontal
 43
 44     # dropout
 45     if dropout > 0.0:
 46         logging.info('use dropout.')
 47         drop = mx.symbol.Dropout(data=h_pool, p=dropout)
 48     else:
 49         logging.info('Do not use dropout.')
 50         drop = h_pool
 51
 52     # fully connected and softmax output.
 53     logging.info('num_classes: %d', num_classes)
 54     logging.info('num_fine_classes: %d', num_fine_classes)
 55     fc = mx.symbol.FullyConnected(data=drop, num_hidden= num_classes, name='fc')
 56     fc_fine = mx.symbol.FullyConnected(data=drop, num_hidden= num_fine_classes, name='fc_fine')
 57     softmax = mx.symbol.SoftmaxOutput(data= fc, label= softmax_label)
 58     softmax_fine = mx.symbol.SoftmaxOutput(data= fc_fine, label= softmax_label_finegrained)
 59
 60     return mx.symbol.Group([softmax, softmax_fine])
```

I've also tried incorporating more information by adding an internal `SoftmaxActivation` layer after `fc` and didn't work:

```
 52     # fully connected and softmax output.
 53     logging.info('num_classes: %d', num_classes)
 54     logging.info('num_fine_classes: %d', num_fine_classes)
 55     fc = mx.symbol.FullyConnected(data=drop, num_hidden= num_classes, name='fc')
 56     softmax = mx.symbol.SoftmaxOutput(data=fc, label= softmax_label)
 57     softmax_act = mx.symbol.SoftmaxActivation(data=fc)
 58     # make softmax_domain a internal layer for emitting activation, which we take it as a input into downstream task.
 59     drop_act = mx.symbol.Concat(drop, softmax_act, dim=1)
 60     fc_fine = mx.symbol.FullyConnected(data=drop_act, num_hidden= num_fine_classes, name='fc_fine')
 61     softmax_fine = mx.symbol.SoftmaxOutput(data=fc_fine, label= softmax_label_finegrained)
 62
 63     return mx.symbol.Group([softmax, softmax_fine])
 64
```

So do you guys have any idea or experience in design such network? Any ideas are welcomed, thank you~

Answer (score 1):

To be honest, I have never seen that multi-task training would be used to improve performance on a fine-grained classification. Both your task are using same network The only difference is that your output of generic classes softmax goes as an input to fine-grained classes softmax.

I don't see where a new information could appear that would be sufficient to improve the performance of the classification of your fine-grained classes.

It is true, that usually people use multi-task learning to learn 2 things at once, but the things that are learnt are kinda independent from each other. Here is [a good example of a problem statement](https://medium.com/@kajalgupta/multi-task-learning-with-deep-neural-networks-7544f8b7b4e3): find the color and the type of a flower. And here is an [example of how to create such a model using MxNet](https://github.com/apache/incubator-mxnet/blob/master/example/multi-task/example_multi_task.py), which is a little bit simpler than yours, because it doesn't connect outputs together.

Hope it helps.